# Area between two polar curves method

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, area

[image]

The question is not too hard. I sketched them and they were correct which was not too bad.

I then did the second part by finding the intersection points between the two curves which are $\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{5\pi}{3}$.

I then integrated:

$$\int_{a}^{b} (r_o^2 - r_i^2)d\theta$$

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{5\pi}{3}} \frac{1}{2}((1-cos(\theta))^2 - (cos(\theta))^2) d\theta$$ and got $\frac{2\pi}{3}$+$\sqrt{3}$ as my answer.

Is my work (and hopefully my answer...) right or did I do something wrong?

Comment: When you integrate $r_0^2-r_1^2$ you calculate the area inside the first curve and outside the second curve - it was supposed to be the other way around. Secondly, your $r_1$ is negative in the interval $\pi/2<\theta<3\pi/2$, so there is no second curve in this sector!! Look at the sketch again, and read the problem again. Also (not really relevant here, but this confuses students who do not sketch), for the polar curves of $r_1$ and $r_2$ to intersect it is not necessary that $r_1=r_2$. The other possibility is that they intersect at origin, if both $r_1$ and $r_2$ vanish at **any** point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

$\displaystyle A=\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}\frac{1}{2}\left((\cos\theta)^2-(1-\cos\theta)^2\right)d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{1}{2}\left((\cos\theta)^2-(1-\cos\theta)^2\right)d\theta$

$\displaystyle\hspace{.16 in}=\int_0^{\pi/3}(2\cos\theta-1)\,d\theta$

Comment: -pi/3 is equivalent to 5pi/3 right? So why not use that instead of -pi/3? I got the rest of it.

Comment: $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ and $-\frac{\pi}{3}$ are coterminal, so you could you use $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{7\pi}{3}$ as the limits instead if you wanted to (but not $\frac{5\pi}{3}$ and $\frac{\pi}{3}$).

Comment: Understood :) . Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Solving $ 1- \cos \theta = \cos \theta, $ we find:

Upper limit $\pi/3 $ is OK, but the lower limit of $\theta $ should be symmetric to zero as $ -\pi/3$ . Else you will get the correct answer. May be you should revisit your sketch.

Comment: Why 0? If I plug in 0 for theta, I do not get 1/2 .

Comment: Why should you get $\frac12$? The limits actually should be $ \pm \pi/3$ symmetrically wrt x-axis.

Comment: Okay so here is where I am confused. 

1) If I use -pi/3 and pi/3 I get a different answer han using 5pi/3 and pi/3 which shold not happen I think

2) I get negative area in either case. Is that normal?

Comment: Never mind. I fixed the negative area mistake. But why do I have to use -pi/3 and pi/3. Is pi/3 and 5pi/3 not equivalent?